# Vanishing of L-function of elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

For an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, it is not very difficult to show $L(E,1)\not=0$ (when the analytic rank$=0$) by computing the several Fourier coefficients but seem to be difficult to determine whether one has $L(E,1)=0$ (when the analytic rank$\not=0$). Is there a small constant $c$ such that, if we have $\mid L(E,1)\mid <c$, one can obtain $L(E,1)=0$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to pick up on something mentioned in @MyNinthAccount's answer:

If you just want to determine whether or not $L(E, 1) = 0$, then there is another approach, which doesn't involve computing $L(E, 1)$ numerically to high precision and then arguing with inequalities. The point is that the ratio 
$$\frac{L(E, 1)}{\Omega^+_E}$$
is not only rational, but is *exactly computable* as a rational number (using modular symbols). So there is an algorithm which will determine, rigorously and in finitely many steps, whether the analytic rank is 0 or not. The standard number theory software packages (Sage, Magma, maybe also Pari) have built-in functionality to do this.

If you find by this method that $L(E, 1) = 0$, then determining what the analytic rank actually is is a much harder problem.

Answer (score 6):

There is not a "constant" $c$ *per se*, but rather an expression in terms of the real period. This follows for instance from Manin's modular symbols theory, that the central $L$-value is a rational multiple (of bounded height) of the real period. More explicitly, you need to include the torsion and Tamagawa number contributions.

Using Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer as a guide, one has
$${L(E,1)\over\Omega}{|T|^2\over \prod c_p}$$
is an integral square (possibly zero), and if it is less than 1 it indeed must vanish (one might need extra factors from Manin constants, I'm not sure).

So there is an implication:
$$L(E,1)<{\prod_p c_p\over |T|^2}\Omega_{\rm re}\implies L(E,1)=0.$$

Comment: That sounds like a conjectural bound, though recent work on BSD proves this almost. One can use the theorem of Manin and Drinfeld to get a better bound. Let $c_0$ be the Manin constant of the strong Weil curve in the isogeny class of $E$. Then $L(E,1)$ is in $\Omega/2/ \vert T\vert /c_0\, \mathbb{Z}$. For semistable curves $c_0$ is known to be $1$ or $2$ for instance, in general it is conjectured to be $1$.

Comment: If you are after a more absolute bound $c$, then the question becomes what the smallest $\Omega$ are. By a conjecture of Goldfeld there is a $k$ such that $\Omega = O(N^{-k})$ as the conductor $N$ increases. The abc conjecture is equivalent to $k=1/2+\varepsilon$ if I remember correctly. Maybe $\Omega> 1/N$ for all curves, I would not know.

Comment: It is probably better to bound $\Omega$ in terms of the discriminant than the conductor.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich There are convexity bounds of the form $L(E,1) \ll N^{1/4}$ if I recall correctly, so together with the bound you mention (and assuming $c_0=1$), this seems to prove $\Omega \ll N^{1/4}$. Maybe it is possible to get a lower bound for the real period using its AGM expression as in Watkins, Some heuristics on elliptic curves, section 3.3. Watkins mentions that $\Omega$ is very roughly $\Delta^{-1/12}$.